# calling a rest api with setInterval and promise in node.js

Tags: node.js, api, promise, setinterval, binance

I'm new to nodejs. I have developed a function that calls a rest API with an interval of one second.

Theoretically I should have a new result every second, but the console only shows me one result. I do not know why.

```
const https = require('https');

const url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT';

const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  let price = '';
  const interval = setInterval(() => {

    https.get(url, (response) => {
      let data = '';

      // A new chunk of data has been received.
      response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });

      // The whole response has been received, print out the result.
      response.on('end', () => {
        // returns formatted price
        price = JSON.parse(data).price;
        price = (price * 100) / 100;
        resolve(price)
      });
    });
  }, 1000);
});

promise.then((price) => {
  console.log('Current price ' + price);
});
```

Comment: Promises only ever resolve once.  They are one-shot devices.  So, `.then()` on any given promise will only ever get called once.  If you want a repeated result (once for each invocation of the interval timer), then you would use an event or a callback, not a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise as a `feature`, resolve `only one time`. You have to create a new promise to post new value. For your case `event emitter` is the best.

```
// const https = require("https")
const promiseOnce = new Promise(r => {
  setInterval(() => {
    const date = new Date();
    r(date);
  }, 1000);
});
promiseOnce.then(x => console.log(x)); // will resolve once
```

> events:: EventEmitter

```
const EventEmitter = require("events");
const priceEmitter = new EventEmitter();
setInterval(() => {
  const date = new Date();
  priceEmitter.emit("price", date);
}, 1000);
priceEmitter.on("price", price => {
  console.log(price); // Will emit always
});
```

Comment: you were right, event emitter is the best for my case, thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the promise inside of the `setInterval` callback.

Also, you might enjoy using an async request package such as [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).

```js
const https = require("https")

const url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT"

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let price = ""
    https.get(url, response => {
      let data = ""

      // A new chunk of data has been received.
      response.on("data", chunk => {
        data += chunk
      })

      // The whole response has been received, print out the result.
      response.on("end", () => {
        // returns formatted price
        price = JSON.parse(data).price
        price = (price * 100) / 100
        resolve(price)
      })
    })
  })
  promise.then(price => {
    console.log("Current price " + price)
  })
}, 1000)
```